# Procerdure for transformation of bivariate to single RV

Tags: self-study, random-variable, joint-distribution

Let's say I have RVs X and Y with joint pdf f(XY). I want to find the pdf of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$. How do I start? I know what to do if this is a transformation from X to some function of X or from (X,Y) to some (U,V) where U and V are functions of X and Y, but what happens in this case? Is it just a simpler case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with.

I want the pdf of $V=\frac{X}{X+Y}$

I did some algebraic manipulations:

$\frac{1}{V}=\frac{X+Y}{X}=1+\frac{Y}{X}$

$\frac{Y}{X}=\frac1V-1$

Now I used the property that for any RVs $Y,X$ with joint pdf $f(X,Y)$, the pdf of their ratio $Z=\frac YX$ is given by $\int|X|f(X,XZ)dX$

I then used the resulting pdf for $Z$ to get the pdf for $V$

$f_v(V)=f_z(\frac 1V-1)\frac{d}{dV}(\frac 1V-1)$

Is this correct? If it is, is it the shortest solution or is there one where I can avoid the use of $\frac YX$?